# How do I pull Elastic-search metrics into Prometheus using the Elasticseacrh_exporter

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have installed Prometheus into a Kubernetes cluster using the helm stable chart. We run Elastic Search and I want to scrape metrics from this and then create Alerts based on events.
I have installed the elasticsearch exporter via helm but no where can I find how I then import these metrics into Prometheus ?

There is some config I am missing such as creating a **scraping** job or something. Anyone can help much appreciated.

I connected to the elasticsearch exporter and can see it pulling metrics.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an *elasticsearch exporter* it should contain some documentation. There are more than just one solution out there and you didn't specify which one you're using. In my opinion it would be best for you to start from a tutorial like [this one](https://medium.com/rahasak/monitor-elasticsearch-with-prometheus-and-grafana-687a0b6712) which explains step by step the whole process. As you can read there:

> Metrics collection of Prometheus follows the pull model. That means,
>   Prometheus is responsible for getting metrics from the services that
>   it monitors. This process introduced as scraping. Prometheus server
>   scrapes the defined service endpoints, collect the matrixes and store
>   in local database.

which means you need to configure **Prometheus** to scrape metrics exposed by the **elasticsearch exporter** you chose.

Official **Prometheus** [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/first_steps/) will be also a great source of knowledge and good starting point.

EDIT:

If you run your Elasticsearch instance on Kubernetes cluster, you should rather use the **Service Discovery** mechanism than static configs. More on `<kubernetes_sd_config>` you can find [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config).

There are *five different types of Kubernetes service discoveries* you can use with Prometheus: `node`, `endpoints`, `service`, `pod`, and `ingress`. The one which you most probably need in your case is `endpoints`. Prometheus uses the Kubernetes API to discover targets. Below you have some examples:

https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/prometheus-kubernetes-discovery
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus/prometheus/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml

Comment: Thanks, I am using the following image image:
  repository: justwatch/elasticsearch_exporter
  I am so close but can't find the correct scrape config. The metrics are exposed on port 9108 via http. I've read the  documentation all I need is an example. The service is exposed on the ClusterIP so how do I tell Prometheus to scrape ClusterIP:9108 ?

Comment: Please see the EDIT of my answer.